# VSCode - Vite Open Browser Shortcut

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vite, key-bindings

I am running **Vue** with **Vite** in **VSCode** on Windows 10. I have the **NPM Scripts** shortcuts that builds the project when clicked on. I added the following binding to **keybindings.json** below and works nicely to launch my site as expected:

```
{
    "key": "alt+g",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
        "text": "npm run dev\r"
    },
},
```

Afterwards, I have to press the **"o"** to invoke the **Vite "open the browser"** command to launch the browser. I would like to incorporate the open command into the keybinding and I have tried several things including changing that text line to:

```
"text": "npm run dev\r && echo 'o'\r" 
// OR
"text": "npm run dev\r && start chrome"
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: what if you use https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_running-multiple-commands ?

Comment: @startball -  good suggestion that works! Not sure it is the most streamlined but it is getting the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @startball's comment above - the following successfully compiles the project with Vite and then launches the website with the default browser.

```
{
    "key": "alt+g",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": 
    {
      "commands":[
        {
            "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
            "args": { "text": "npm run dev\r" }
        },
        {
            "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
            "args": { "text": "o" }
        }
      ]
    }
},
```